# Alternative to Remote Desktop Connection to clean C drive

Tags: networking, remote-desktop, windows-server-2008, remote

We have some issue in connecting the server via Remote Desktop Connection. It is not at all connecting

As the server got low memory space in c drive we are unable to connect.

I would like to know is there any way, we connect the Server using IP address and goto C drive and delete unwanted files?

I have only IP address and do not aware of where the server is located physically.
Any command prompt utility can help us for this?

Comment: Is there another computer you can RDP into which is on the same network as the server?

Comment: @DaveRook, Yes I can able to connect with other system in the same network. But this server is simply showing connecting.... message for long time.

Answer (score 0):

Why use RDP at all?  If all you are trying to do is clean the C: drive, you can connect directly to the drive through Windows File Explorer.  Open a File Explorer and type `\\localhost\c$` in the address bar.  Replace `localhost` with the machine's name or IP address.  I am assuming you have administrator access, since you are able to RDP to the machine and have access to the C: drive.

Answer (score 0):

If you have an administrative account, you can browse to \IP\c$ and get to the Admin share of the C drive.

You could also connect with WMI and [list / remove files by script](http://blogs.technet.com/b/softienerd/archive/2009/04/22/delete-remote-files-via-wmi-and-powershell.aspx), but I don't know any program that will present it neatly. [DameWare](http://www.dameware.com/) Remote Support free trial might.

If you can install some things, but RDP is broken, then [PSExec from SysInternals](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897553) will let you run a command prompt on a remote computer. It does need Admin rights, and to push a small service file though.

These often help me - it depends how much access you have (permissions and firewall open ports/allowed kinds of connections), how much disk space there is, and precisely what is broken.